# Adding texts into Textview from sqlite database with rowID

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've a list view which is populated by my database. Now in the `OnItemClickListener` I passed the row id to the next `Activity`. In that activity I have two text views and I want to add texts in those text views from the my database.

As a beginner I'm stuck here, What should I do now?

Comment: Please clarify the question and include any code that you can. Without code, we have no idea what is going on!

Answer (score 0):

If the id(not the position of the item in the listviw) you are passing to the next activity is primary key or it is mapped somehow  to your database table then you can simply query your database with a where clause to get the specific row from the table.

Another simple solution may be passing the data from the same activity to the another activity over the intent (if they are some small size), instead of making another query to the database tables.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in the row id to the database:

```
SqliteDatabase mySqlLiteDatabase;

View parentThis = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view);
lvDatabase = (ListView)parentThis.findViewById(R.id.listview);
lvDatabase.setAdapter(String[] list_Of_Items_From_Database);
lvDatabase.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              sql = "Select text from my_database where _id=" + id;
              mySqlLiteDatabase.openDatabase(yourDatabasePath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
              Cursor c = mySqlLiteDatabase.rawquery(sql);
              TextView textView = (TextView)parentThis.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
              if (c !=null) { 
                 if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
                       textView.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Text")));
                 }
              }
        }
});
```

Hopefully your database table has an identity column in it (`_id`)

Answer (score 0):

pass all the data in  an array by quering into db and then display it in listView.

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllNumbers(){
        ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String number=cursor.getString(1);
                labels.add(number);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }
```

then fetch it on item click of listview  and pass it to another activity.

```
@Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    final View view, final int position, long arg3) {
           title = view.getTag(R.string.title).toString();
Intent intent_compose = new Intent(ActivityA.this,
                ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intent_compose);

}
```

Comment: Figured that our, Thanks! :)